# two csv and one excel

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary, compare

Need a hand on how to compare two technically same json files and output the differences between them.

Comment: It's not clear what your input and output json objects would look like. Could you include examples of both, and of the python code that you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
diff = {}

for k, v in ref.items():
    diff[k] = {}
    for key, ref_value in v.items():
        if key in exact_match_keys:
            if ref_value == samp[k][key]:
                diff[k][key] = "matched"
            else:
                diff[k][key] = "Not Matched"
        elif key in percent_match_keys:
            ref_n, samp_n = float(ref_value), float(samp[k][key])
            p_dif = abs(ref_n - samp_n) / ref_n * 100
            diff[k][key] = f"%{p_dif} difference"
```

Comment: I could not express my gratitude to you enough!

Comment: I would appriciate if you can give the idea how to generate the expected output!>?